# do repetitive tasks at intervals in golang using time.AfterFunc, just a sample

Tags: go

I just want to do repetitive background tasks in Go, using time.AfterFunc,But seems something wrong with the logic. 
The out put just:
interval call
interval call

But at least 5 times to call the function if all things went normal.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)

type Timer struct {
    Queue chan *TimeCall
}

func NewTimer(l int) *Timer {
    timer := new(Timer)
    timer.Queue = make(chan *TimeCall,l)
    return timer
}

type TimeCall struct {
    timer    *time.Timer
    callback func()
}

func (this *TimeCall) CallBack() {
    defer func() { recover() }()
    if this.callback != nil {
        this.callback()
    }
}

func (this *Timer) AfterFunc(d time.Duration, callback func()) *TimeCall {
    call := new(TimeCall)
    call.callback = callback
    call.timer = time.AfterFunc(d, func() {
        this.Queue <- call
    })
    return call
}



type PipeService struct {
    TimeCall *Timer
}

func (this *PipeService) AfterFunc(delay time.Duration, callback func()) *TimeCall {
    return this.TimeCall.AfterFunc(delay, callback)
}

func (this *PipeService) IntervalCall(interval time.Duration, callback func()) {
    this.TimeCall.AfterFunc(interval,func(){
        if callback != nil {
            callback()
        }
        this.AfterFunc(interval,callback)
    })
}

func (this *PipeService) Run(closeSig chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-closeSig:
            return
        case call := <-this.TimeCall.Queue:
            call.CallBack()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var closeChan chan bool
    InsPipeService := &PipeService{TimeCall: NewTimer(10)}
    InsPipeService.IntervalCall(2*time.Second,func(){
        fmt.Println("interval call")
    })

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

    go func(){
        InsPipeService.Run(closeChan)
    }()

    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```

[Run Code](http://ideone.com/vk3t4q)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`time.AfterFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc) returns a [`*time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer), quoting form its doc:

> The Timer type represents a **single event**. When the Timer expires, the current time will be sent on C, unless the Timer was created by AfterFunc.

The `time.Timer` returned by `time.AfterFunc()` does not repeat, so what you see is perfectly normal: in your `PipeService.IntervalCall()` you execute the callback immediately, and it gets executed after the timeout.

Also note that you pass `2` as interval for the `PipeService.IntervalCall()` method. This `interval` parameter is of type [`time.Duraion`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration). So when you pass `2`, that won't be 2 seconds (but actually 2 nanoseconds). You should pass a value constructed from constants from the `time` package like:

```
InsPipeService.IntervalCall(2 * time.Second, func(){
    fmt.Println("interval call")
})
```

If you want repetition, use [`time.Ticker`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker). For example the following code prints a message in every 2 seconds:

```
t := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
for now := range t.C {
    fmt.Println("tick", now)
}
```

Or simply if you don't need the `Ticker` and you don't want to shut it down:

```
c := time.Tick(2 * time.Second)
for now := range c {
        fmt.Println("tick", now)
}
```

Comment: it's a mistake, code has updated, i know that using time.Ticker is a better way, but i just want to know why my code run like that.

Answer (score 0):

set time interval then call Start it will run user Job on each time intervals. set Enabled to false to stop it.
My Sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type IntervalTimer struct {
    Interval time.Duration
    Enabled  bool
    Job      func()
    Wg       sync.WaitGroup
}

func (it *IntervalTimer) isr() {
    if it.Enabled {
        it.Job()
        time.AfterFunc(it.Interval, it.isr)
    } else {
        it.Wg.Done()
    }
}

//trigger
func (it *IntervalTimer) Start() {
    if it.Enabled {
        it.Wg.Add(1)
        time.AfterFunc(it.Interval, it.isr)
    }
}

// user code:
var n int = 5
var it *IntervalTimer

func uerTask() {
    fmt.Println(n, time.Now()) // do user job ...
    n--
    if n == 0 {
        it.Enabled = false
    }
}
func main() {
    it = &IntervalTimer{Interval: 500 * time.Millisecond, Enabled: true, Job: uerTask}
    it.Start()

    //do some job ...
    it.Wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Bye")
}
```